# Github Quandl not able to install

Tags: r, github-api, quandl

When I tried installing quandl it is showing this error message. Can anyone help ??

```
> install_github("quandl/R-package")
Downloading GitHub repo quandl/R-package@master
Installing Quandl
Installing 1 packages: stringi
package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘stringi’
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/saikitti/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqoWawf/devtools25b4184b2cd/quandl-quandl-r-9182d61"  \
  --library="C:/Users/saikitti/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'Quandl' ...
** R
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'stringi'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'Quandl'
* removing 'C:/Users/saikitti/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Quandl'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `Depends:`:

```
 there is no package called 'stringi'
```

But Quandl is on CRAN, so why don't you do `install.packages("Quandl")` ?

Comment: I'm getting errors with the supported installation as well..  not finding dependencies that I should have like openSSL, curl, etc..

Comment: In order to _build from source_ you need the build-dependencies, ie `libcurl-dev`, `libopenssl-dev` and alike.  Seek local help from a more experienced user, maybe a colleague or friend.